# How to add country phone number prefix in webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a webform, with a field for phone number.

I would like to have another select dropdown field before phone number, with country name and country phone number prefix.

Eg:
Singapore (65)
United Kingdom (44)
Venezuela (58)

Comment: Have you tried https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_phone ?

Comment: Yes I had tried this, but it does not provides a drop down in the webform, for user to choose their country with country phone code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webform allows you to load options in bulk. Just google for this list and load it into a spreadsheet. Use a bit of find/replace to get it into the format needed by a webform select element, which is:

```
65|Singapore (65)
44|United Kingdom (44)
58|Venezuela (58)
```

Then create a webform select field and paste it in.

To get the fields to line up side-by-side (with country code right before phone number and not on a separate line) use the [webform_layout](https://drupal.org/project/webform_layout) module.

Comment: I forgot about this options in bulk! Thank you so much!

Comment: This is not a good solution because some countries have the same prefix, so some keys have the same value and this is not allowed

Comment: You'd have to consolidate the duplicates onto a single line, e.g. if both Country A and Country B share the code `123`, then put them on the same line like this:

`123|Country A/CountryB (123)`